# I can't type "<" in the text value of button?

Tags: android, button, text

I want to type `<` in the button text for going previous on the list or go to next, but when I try `>` there is no problem but for `<` it gives me an error!

```
 <Button
        android:text=">"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnPrev1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
```

The error:

> Error:(24) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: You can set your character during findview by id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's true, you have to use `&lt;` instead of `<`. In strings.xml you can also use CDATA:

```
 <string name="samplehtml"><![CDATA[<i>formatted</i> <b>text</b>]]/>
```

In your case:

```
<Button
    android:text="&lt;"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnPrev1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>
```

Comment: Basically, escape the char so Android understands the char has no importance

Comment: tnx for your help , but where can i find the code like this one?